# I got blank space at text area in every update time

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, textarea

```
<textarea name="email_message" id="email_message" cols="65" rows="15"><?php echo trim($entry['message']);?></textarea>
```

When I update with above html code it make twice of blank line which contain in message.

eg :

```
Dear Sir
(here is one now now)
How are you?
```

when it update to database it save like :

```
Dear Sir
(here is two lines)

How are you?
```

It increase blank line in every save.

PHP code is here :

```
function email_template_save()
    {
        $content = $this->input->post('email_message');
        $this->load->model('templates');
        $data['msg']=$this->templates->update_email_template($content,$this->session->userdata('username'));
        $data['main_content']='message';
        $this->load->view('template',$data);

    }


function update_email_template($content,$username)
    {
        $data=array(
            'message'=>$this->input->post('email_message'));
            $this->db->where('username', $username);
            $this->db->update('email_format', $data); 
            return 'Successfully Updated';


    }
```

Comment: Can you please show the php-code you use to update the db?

Comment: I have updated with PHP code. Thank you

Comment: Would be good to see update_email_template() too.

Comment: I have put that update_email_template() too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know all about this, it's an issue with the latest release of CI and Windows newlines.

See this answer: [PHP textarea saving extra new lines to MySQL DB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4967761/php-textarea-saving-extra-new-lines-to-mysql-db/5397078#5397078)

This is the workaround I'm using, extension of the input class:

```
<?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access.');

/**
 * CI 2.0 (Reactor version) did something funny to newlines.
 * Textareas would $_POST an extra newline, this is a patch for that "feature".
 * 
 * @package     Codeigniter
 * @subpackage  Input
 */
class MY_Input extends CI_Input {

    public function __construct()
    {
        if (PHP_EOL == "\r\n")
        {
            $this->_standardize_newlines = FALSE;
        }
        parent::__construct();
    }
}
/* end file */
```

This is related to your other question as well: [explode error \r\n and \n in windows and linux server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5769589/explode-error-r-n-and-n-in-windows-and-linux-server)

See here for an explanation on that: [When do I use the PHP constant "PHP_EOL"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/128560/when-do-i-use-the-php-constant-php-eol)

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that the blanks are represented going in as `\r\n` and when your print them, the `\r` and the `\n` separate?  Try running `<textarea name="email_message" id="email_message" cols="65" rows="15"><?php echo trim(str_replace("\r\n","\n",$entry['message']));?></textarea>`

Comment: It is not working. I am running on windows (PHP 5.3). Is OS matter?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that you are escaping the values twice, i had the same issue recently, check if you are escaping the value in both getting the post and in saving the data.