# explode error \r\n and \n in windows and linux server

Tags: php, textarea, explode

I have used explode function to get textarea's contain into array based on line. When I run this code in my localhost (WAMPserver 2.1) It work perfectly with this code :

```
$arr=explode("\r\n",$getdata);
```

When I upload to my linux server I need to change above code everytime into :

```
$arr=explode("\n",$getdata);
```

What will be the permanent solution to me. Which common code will work for me for both server?

Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The constant PHP_EOL contains the platform-dependent linefeed, so you can try this:

```
$arr = explode(PHP_EOL, $getdata);
```

But even better is to normalize the text, because you never know what OS your visitors uses. This is one way to normalize to only use \n as linefeed (but also see Alex's answer, since his regex will handle all types of linefeeds):

```
$getdata = str_replace("\r\n", "\n", $getdata);
$arr = explode("\n", $getdata);
```

Comment: Some operating systems use \r as a newline though, you need to deal with that too.

Comment: GordonM, you are correct. The ten year old Mac OS 9 uses \r (as well as some systems from the 80's), but I don't think anyone is running a web server on that old software.

Comment: True enough, but it never hurts to keep your bases covered :)

Comment: The `PHP_EOL` constant is relative to the server environment, the input data might have other origins.

Comment: Alix, true, that's why it's better to normalize the input. Your regex may be the best solution (I'm clarifying my answer as well, but not stealing your fame :-)).

Answer (score 6):

As far as I know the best way to split a string by newlines is [`preg_split`](http://php.net/preg_split) and [`\R`](http://www.pcre.org/pcre.txt):

```
preg_split('~\R~', $str);
```

`\R` matches any Unicode Newline Sequence, i.e. not only `LF`, `CR`, `CRLF`, but also more exotic ones like `VT`, `FF`, `NEL`, `LS` and `PS`.

If that behavior isn't wanted (why?), you could specify the `BSR_ANYCRLF` option:

```
preg_split('~(*BSR_ANYCRLF)\R~', $str);
```

This will match the "classic" newline sequences only.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the best approach would be to normalize your input data to just use `\n`, like this:

```
$input = preg_replace('~\r[\n]?~', "\n", $input);
```

Since:

- Unix uses `\n`.
- Windows uses `\r\n`.
- (Old) Mac OS uses `\r`.

---

Nonetheless, exploding by `\n` should get you the best results (if you don't normalize).

Answer (score 0):

The PHP_EOL constant contains the character sequence of the host operating system's newline.

```
$arr=explode(PHP_EOL,$getdata);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `preg_split()` which will allow it to work regardless:

```
$arr = preg_split('/\r?\n/', $getdata);
```