# PHP_EOL on Windows and Linux

Tags: php, linux, newline

In my web application, I create a `formula` which uses a `textarea` to take a list of IDs (in hex). The user have to separate them by pressing `return` after entering every ID.

```
<label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="id_list">IDs: </label>
<div class="col-md-9>
    <textarea class="form-control" id="id_list" name="id_list" required></textarea>
</div>
```

Then, I send this list to the server for processing (in PHP):

```
$id_list = trim($_POST['id_list'];
$id_array = explode(PHP_EOL, $id_list);

// file_put_contents('/tmp/bla.txt', $id_array);

for($i = 0; $i < count($id_array); $i++){
  // Do stuff
}

// Now I want to save the ids in a string which will separate the ids with ","
$id_string = str_replace(PHP_EOL, ',', $id_list)
```

This works fine on a Windows server. However, on a Linux server it seems to have problem with `PHP_EOL`; when I put the result from `explode(PHP_EOL, $id_list)` in a txt file and examine it in *Notepad++*, the `CR` is still there.

I tried different ways`'\n','\r\n',...`, but it seems using `PHP_EOL` is the only way where `explode(PHP_EOL, $id_list)` works in Windows.

What can I do to make it working on both Windows AND Linux?

Comment: Did you try escaping the newline characters? e.g. `\\r\\n`?

Comment: Did you try using ``nl2br()`` function?

Comment: if i read http://stackoverflow.com/a/14217315/5378743  correctly linebreaks in textareas are  always (no matter which operating system) send as `"\r\n"`.

Comment: I just found my mistake, and its a stupid one... \r\n works fine on both Windows and Linux. BUT I need to put them in `""` and not `''`. After I changed that, everything works fine

Comment: strange though, in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5769589/explode-error-r-n-and-n-in-windows-and-linux-server , someone had problem with "\r\n" on both platform and PHP_EOL was suggested as solution, but here is just the other way around. Does something changed since 2011?

Answer (score 1):

I actually (almost) had the right answer. \r\n works on both systems, but I just made the mistake putting them in `''` (single quotes) when `""` (double quotes) should be used here:

```
explode("\r\n", $id_list)
str_replace("\r\n", ',', $id_list)
```

It is both working on Windows and Linux now.

Answer (score 0):

```
$id_list = trim($_POST['id_list']);
$id_array = explode("\n", $id_list);
$id_array = array_filter($id_array, 'trim');
foreach ($id_array as $line) {
    // do stuff here
}
```

This should work, you explode on "\n" and trim any left over "\r" (if any).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use `preg_split`, therefore a regex:

```
$id_array = preg_split('#[\s,]+#Sui', $id_list);
```

So you have an array of ID, whatever the input format is. You can check the manual entry for this function in *[preg_split](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php)* (php.net).